# implementing IF action in ANTLR4/JS

Tags: antlr4

Trying to adapt an ANTLR3 application (in C++) into ANTLR4 (in JS), I still don't understand how to implement a IF THEN ELSE ENDIF in my language.
Preferably using embedded actions because my app is simple, but I accept any alternative as hint (since I'm stuck for weeks, despite the book). Please help !

typical context:

```
stat:   cmd SEPARATOR
    |   SEPARATOR  
    ;
cmd: ...
   | 'if' c=e 'then' y=stat ( el='else' n=stat )? 'endif'
                   {  *ACTION* }
   ;
```

NB: In ANTLR3, *ACTION* used to be as simple as

```
             stat( $c.getNextSibling().getFirstChild() );
          else 
             stat( $c.getNextSibling().getNextSibling() );
```

But I still don't understand how to do it in ANTLR4/JS (in direct action, visitor, listener, or whatever).

Thanks !

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: what kind of MCVE ? for the syntax ?
our language is quite classical. e.g.: IF x<0 THEN x:0 ; y:0 ENDIF  ( + optional ELSE), with any legal condition or statements,  decribed by rules e (for expressions) and stat (for statments).